# Touch events on Transperent Image in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am having one problem. I have 3 images(img1, img2, img3), among one is transparent and other two images are placed below of the transparent image. img1 is placed below(like background image) and img2 is placed above of img2 and at last img3(transparent image). I want to do action for img2 but touch events are not occurring on top of the transparent image(img3). Is there any way to fire touch events on img2?
Please help me to resolve this..
Thanks in Advance..

Code..

```
$('#bgTrnsImg').bind('touchend',function(e){
    $('#smallDustBean1').trigger('touchend');
});

$('#smallDustBean1').bind('click touchend',function(e){
    SpriteSheetExample1();
    alert("T1");
    // Does something special
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#bgTrnsImg').bind('touchend',function(e){
    $('#smallDustBean2').trigger('touchend');
});

$('#smallDustBean2').bind('click touchend',function(e){
    SpriteSheetExample2();
    alert("T2");
    // Does something special
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#bgTrnsImg').bind('touchend',function(e){
    $('#smallDustBean3').trigger('touchend');
});

$('#smallDustBean3').bind('click touchend',function(e){
    SpriteSheetExample3();
    alert("T3");
    // Does something special
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#bgTrnsImg').bind('touchend',function(e){
    $('#smallDustBean4').trigger('touchend');
});

$('#smallDustBean4').bind('click touchend',function(e){
    SpriteSheetExample4();
    alert("T4");
    // Does something special
    e.stopPropagation();
});


$('#bgTrnsImg').bind('touchend',function(e){
         $('#smallDustBean5').trigger('touchend');
    });

$('#smallDustBean5').bind('click touchend',function(e){
        SpriteSheetExample5();
        alert("T5");
        // Does something special
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

I am updating my code, according below answer, events are triggering on every touch of transparent image NOT on particular img2(smallDustBeans) only.
and img1 z-index is 1, img2 z-index is 2 and img3 z-index is 3 in HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi finally I found the answer here http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/

set up pointer-events: none; on the img3, and they will act as they're invisible to pointer (and touch) events.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between click and touch event.

If you want to implicitly fire touch on a specific event use like this.

```
$('#img3').bind('touchend',function(e)
{
    $('#img2').trigger('touchend');
});

$('#img2').bind('click touchend',function(e)
{
    // Does something special
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: A.. thanks for response, I have checked with touchstart also..I will check and get back to you

Comment: Use touchend, because user can move his fingers out of the image. Alternatively you can combine touchmove event...

Comment: Ya I have check with your answer, Its not working sir:-( Have you got my problem because my English bad..

Comment: Ya i have tried with touchend but not working. img2 is not taking touch event because of transparent image

Comment: Yes you are right, it will not fire, unless you change z-index of img2 to 3, check my answer again.

Comment: using img3 you can fire events of img2

Comment: events are triggering on every touch of transparent image(img3) NOT on particular img2(smallDustBeans) only

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery mobile js for touch events

```
$("#img2").on("tap",function(){
  alert("Touched");
}
```

Comment: without jquery mobile. Is it possible to achieve??